# Is the pet yard accessible to everyone or just me?

Tags: realm-of-the-mad-god

Is the pet yard on Realm of the Mad God your pet yard or everyone's pet yard?  I don't want people stealing MY pets.

Answer (score 6):

Each user has his or her own pet yard. According to the [official forums](https://web.archive.org/web/20130510180442/https://forums.wildshadow.com/node/196222):

> Now you can access this **personal** haven through a portal in your Vault.

Answer (score 0):

Another person can not access your pet yard. Only you can look at it. But there is still one way someone can look at your pets, on realmeye.